# Issue on verifying user login name and password

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

Friends I need to make a software that needs to verifies the valid user login in order to use software. I tried this:

```
bool valid = false;
 using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,domainname))
 {
     valid = context.ValidateCredentials( username, password );
 }
```

I am using .net framework 4 . In this above code how to get domainname of the computer.
I have tried
`SystemInformation.ComputerName` ,`SystemInformation.UserDomainName` 
but i got error as :

> The server could not be contacted

. 
And Can we get the current username and password using any header file in c# ??
Please answer.
Edits:
I am using this for local login in my computer or AD.

Comment: So you want to verify that the user is a valid Windows user on the local server? Integrated Windows Authentication?

Comment: yes.But there may be autologin so with asking credentials ..

Comment: Are you trying to do this against AD (Active Directory)

Comment: And of course, no, you cannot read the current user's password.

Comment: you will get errors because you are not passing the correct ActiveDirectory DC or Domain info this site will help you ..that is if you are using ActiveDirectory..  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924542%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: What does the top of your .cs File Header look like in the "using" section do you have this..? using System.Security;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way to get the user's password.  That could lead to all sorts of security issues.  And if you want to verify credentials beyond what the machine already knows from the Windows logon you need to ask the user for the password anyway.

The following code works for me in a forest with many domains.  If you don't specify a domain in the `PrincipalContext` constructor it connects to the domain of the computer it's running on.  In my testing it doesn't matter if the user you're validating is in a different domain, as long as appropriate trusts exist between the domains in the forest.

```
bool valid = false;
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    valid = context.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
}
```

You can get an object representing the current user like this:

```
var user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
```

**Update**

If you're wanting to check credentials against the local account database on the machine then just change the type of the `PrincipalContext`:

```
bool valid = false;
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
{
    valid = context.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
}
```

Comment: Which line gives you the error.  Are you sure your machine is in an AD domain?  Does the account you're running under have permissions to bind to the domain?

Comment: `PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)`

Comment: Is the machine you're running on a member of a domain the forest you're trying to connect to?

Comment: i want to connect to my computer only... just verify if the user accessing my software is a valid user or not..

Comment: Then change the context type to `ContextType.Machine`. The principal context is then you're local machine, but then you're checking the credentials against the local account database. You won't be able to verify an account in an AD domain.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have .NET 3.5 Installed as well

```
bool valid = false;  
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{      
    valid = context.ValidateCredentials( username, password );  
}
```

Comment: The server could not be contacted. error occured in this also

Comment: If you just specify the `ContextType.Domain` in the constructor it will automatically bind to the domain of the machine the code is running on.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't want to use the domain name of the computer. You want to use the domain name of the user logged in to the computer. This is because some networks can have a trust, where the computer is on one domain, but users on another domain can also log in.

So, to get the domain name of the user currently logged in to windows, you can use this (VB.NET example, but easy enough to covert to C#):

```
Dim arr As String() = My.User.Name.Split("\")

If (arr.Length > 0) Then

    Dim domainName As String = arr(0).ToString
    Dim userName As String = arr(1).ToString.ToLower

End If
```

Now to validate the user's Windows login again before starting your app, you have to make this Windows API call:

```
Private Declare Auto Function LogonUser Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal lpszUsername As String, _
                                                            ByVal lpszDomain As String, _
                                                            ByVal lpszPassword As String, _
                                                            ByVal dwLogonType As Integer, _
                                                            ByVal dwLogonProvider As Integer, _
                                                            ByRef phToken As IntPtr) As Boolean

Const LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE As Long = 2
Const LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK As Long = 3

Public Function ValidateLogin(ByVal domainName As String, ByVal uid As String, ByVal pwd As String) As Boolean

    Dim token As IntPtr

    Return LogonUser(uid, domainName, pwd, LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, token)

End Function
```

Comment: please modify your question to specify exacatly what you are running this against. for example are you looking at AD or LDAP? What type of Server / Network Credentials are you working against..?? what you are wanting to check falls under System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Comment: -1 for VB-specific stuff in a C# question, and use of P/Invoke where there's a perfectly good API already in .Net

Comment: -1 for VB.NET? Are you kidding me? It's all .NET. I've had gotten help and given help a lot between C# for VB.NET and vise-versa. Wake up.

Comment: The -1 was not for VB.Net per-se, but for the use of the `My` object which is specifically VB, and has no parallel in C# without adding a reference to the VB runtime library.  That aside though, even if your answer was in C# I would have down-voted the use of P/Invoke where an acceptable API already exists in the .Net class libraries.