# Optimization Issue in windows login verification

Tags: c#, optimization, .net-4.0

As my previous issue. 
[Issue in login in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933684/issue-on-verifying-user-login-name-and-password/8934189#8934189)

I found this as useful.

```
public bool islogged(string username,string password)
    {
        bool isValid = false;
        using(PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
        {
            isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
        }
        return isValid;
    }
```

But When I used this. It takes more time if you send wrong credentials. So any optimization solution??

Comment: Now this is one thing you _don't_ want to optimize.

Comment: @Henk Is that why nobody wanted to implement my great suggestion of returning at which position one mistyped the password to enable people to easier fix their mistakes? :(

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with optimization. Learn OS mainteannce basics.

> It takes more time if you send wrong credentials

Yes,. This is a standard approach from stoping peopel to brute force thousands of attempts per second. Every fail blocks return for some time. Either change it - may be psosible via group opolicy - or realize it is there for a erason. People are not supposed to enter wrong passwords often.

Comment: Not really true - well ok it's probably what MS also thought when implementing this, but it doesn't do anything useful. We're checking a LOCAL password in the above code, hence we already have control of all the data. I can easily do the checks with a self written program instead of using the official API..

Comment: that's true. But there may be certain mistype.. people doesnt have to pay for that.. @TomTom